# pnpm build error:ELIFECYCLE Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: build, pnpm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFN9O.png)

err info:
node_modules/.pnpm/emoji-mart-vue-fast@11.1.1_vue@3.2.33/node_modules/emoji-mart-vue-fast/src/utils/store.js ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

env: node 16.20.0 、pnpm 8.6.10 os: docker ubuntu:20.04

step 1:  pnpm install,create `node_modules`,no problem..
step 2:  after pnpm build,occur the problem.

can you help me ?  i try del node_moduls and cache,still this problem.

I try more exec cmd:

1. rm -rf $(pnpm store path)
2. rm -rf node_modules
3. pnpm install
4. pnpm build

other i tried node 16.15,still this problem